# Quickest way to create a PDF on-the-fly for testing?

Tags: php, pdf

I want to easily create a simple PDF file with some text in it. Ideally, I would like to be able to use the php function: file_put_contents(). So, in a perfect world something like this would make my day:

```
create_pdf($location, $text);
```

So I could call it:

```
create_pdf("/var/temp.pdf", "hello world").
```

This would create a PDF at /var/temp.pdf with the words "hello world" in it. Without getting an overcomplicated class or library to create PDFs, is there perhaps a simple way to generate a PDF like this using pure PHP?

I don't want to use a libary, so perhaps there is a way to get a PDF base 64 encoded and use it like that, just altering the bits where I want the text to change?

Comment: Have a look at FPDF. Create a simple function using their class. http://www.fpdf.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF format is pretty complex. Even a simple file with little text will be at least 600 bytes big.

You might want to check out [this sample file](http://www.virtualmechanics.com/support/tutorials-spinner/Simple.pdf%5d) which has ~179 words in it yet is 3KB big.

Using a PDF library such as FPDF (http://www.fpdf.org/) or tcpdf (http://www.tcpdf.org) (which IMHO is much better and easier to use) would be much easier if you want a pure PHP way to generate PDF files.